Polkadot js api not working properly causing issues after the recent upgrade
  RPC-CORE: submitAndWatchExtrinsic(extrinsic: Extrinsic): ExtrinsicStatus:: 1002: Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed

WASM backtrace:
error while executing at wasm backtrace:
0: 0x3f0747 - !rust_begin_unwind
1: 0x20fc - !core::panicking::panic_fmt::hbb5a6b42001bdfec
2: 0x3461ca - !TaggedTransactionQueue_validate_transaction: RuntimeApi, Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm unreachable instruction executed\nWASM backtrace:\nerror while executing at wasm backtrace:\n    0: 0x3f0747 - !rust_begin_unwind\n    1: 0x20fc - !core::pa…
How to fix this issue i tried to update packages but nothing worked it was working a week ago but now causing error
const send = await api.tx.nfts.setPrice(collectionId, ItemId, price, whiteListAddress)
  .signAndSend(connectedAccount && connectedAccount.address, { signer: injector.signer }, ({ status }) => {
    if (status.isInBlock) {
      toast.success(`Completed at block hash #${status.asInBlock.toString()}` , {
        position: "top-right",
        autoClose: 5000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined,
        theme: "colored",
        });
        const toastId = toast.info('Transaction is processing', {
          position: "top-right",
          autoClose: false, // Set autoClose to false to keep the toast visible
          hideProgressBar: false,
          closeOnClick: false,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          draggable: true,
          progress: undefined,
          theme: "colored",
          isLoading: true, // This shows the loading indicator
        });
      
        // Simulate an async action, e.g., sending an NFT
        setTimeout(() => {
          toast.update(toastId, {
            render: 'successfully delisted',
            type: 'success',
            isLoading: false,
            autoClose: 5000, // Close the toast after 5 seconds
            closeOnClick: true,
          });
        }, 30000); // Example delay for the async action (e.g., 25 seconds)=
    } else {
      toast.info(`Current status: ${status.type}` , {
        position: "top-right",
        autoClose: 25009,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined,
        theme: "colored",
        });
    }
}).catch((error) => {
  toast.error(`Transaction failed' ${error}` , {
    position: "top-right",
    autoClose: 5000,
    hideProgressBar: false,
    closeOnClick: true,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    draggable: true,
    progress: undefined,
    theme: "colored",
    });
});


You may check the SignedExtension of js api in consistent with the upgraded runtime config.
